# The file format and the extension of filename.xls don't match. This file could be corrupted and unsafe

Tags: php, phpexcel, export-to-excel

I had made a PHP script to output **an excel(.xls) document** from data extracted from MySQL database.

Exporting function is working fine.

The problem is when i open it on MS Excel it shows me following message before opening the file.

**The file format and the extension of filename.xls don't match. This file could be corrupted and unsafe...**

can you help me to resolve this warning message issue?

excel warning message:

[image: excel warning message]

array to be exported to excel:

> [image: array to be exported to excel]

exported file:

> [image: exported file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may change the extension to .xlsx, as MS Office 2013 or newer versions expects that as standard. Also try to use exact mime type when exported from php. you may search for mime types and test which meets your office installation.

Comment: I used .xlsx extension but it didn't resolve that issue.

Comment: Can you upload one excel file here? That will help diagnosis.

Comment: how can i upload a file here?

Comment: upload to any free file sharing or google drive and share the link

Comment: I analyze your so-called excel file and found that its not an excel file at all!!! Its a plain text file with plain text data, separated with space. A valid MS-excel file is not a plain text file, you can check yourself by opening a valid excel document with notepad. You excel generating library somehow messed with the file creation. You should look deeper into documentation or try to find another library which can generate valid excel file.